# Drush: difference between pm-update pm-updatecode

Tags: drush

What's the difference between [pm-update](http://drush.ws/#pm-update) and [pm-updatecode](http://drush.ws/#pm-updatecode)? I reviewed this in the Drush documentation, but they sound the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pm-update` also runs the `update.php` script to take care of any database schema changes that a module may need (same as `drush updatedb`), `pm-updatecode` doesn't.  Under many/most circumstances, you can just run `pm-update`.